# PDFKit using express (Node)

Tags: javascript, asp.net, node.js, pdf, pdfkit

I intend to generate PDF files from asp.net page after getting inputs from the users.

One approach I'm using now is to allow users to run the browser to invoke the server for the creation of the pdf. I choose PDFKit and Express in Node.js for this purpose. I thought of finding C# equivalent - however asp.net core cannot reference external libraries I require for my usage. I can only use the Nuget Package Manager to download libraries and most of the intended libraries are  not support in asp.net core (yet).

**What's Currently Working**

Currently the generation of the pdf script ('pdf.js') is working.
ie.

Running the following command generates the PDF

```
node pdf.js
```

pdf.js

```
var doc = new PDFDocument();
doc.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('out.pdf'));
doc.save()
   .moveTo(100, 150)
   .lineTo(100, 250)
   .lineTo(200, 250)
   .fill("#FF3300")
doc.end()
```

**What I need**

I intended to invoke the node script from the client browser.
I currently use a client script (client.js) to invoke the pdf.js script. I now change the pdf.js script to the following:

Updated (pdf.js)

```
var express = require('express')
var PDFDocument = require('pdfkit');
var fs = require('fs');
var app = express()

app.post('/', function(req,res)
{
  doc.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('out.pdf'));
  doc.save()
   .moveTo(100, 150)
   .lineTo(100, 250)
   .lineTo(200, 250)
   .fill("#FF3300")
  doc.end()
})
```

client.js

```
$('#some-button').click(function() {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'http://localhost:27724/js/pdf.js'
  });
});
```

startClient.cshtml

```
 <td>
       <button id='some-button'>Test</button>
       <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
       <script src='~/js/client.js'></script>
       </td>
 </td>
```

Clicking the button "Test" on cshtml does not generates the out.pdf as I intended.
I need assistance here.

Comment: Searching nuget.org for 'pdf netcore' returns PDF libraries that work on .NET Core. Your approach above seems very convoluted and prone to errors. You'll have a lot of headaches maintaining this in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) set express app listen port like

```
app.listen(27724, function () {
     console.log('Example app listening on port 27724!');
});
```

2) you forgot

```
var doc = new PDFDocument();
```

3) run

```
node pdf.js
```

4) set correct url to ajax request like

```
$('#some-button').click(function() {
   $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'http://localhost:27724'
   });
});
```

Comment: Will be learning how to pass information using jquery + json via express